# Android AlertDialog not showing

Tags: android, android-alertdialog

I can't get my alert dialog to show.  I've put it into debug mode and it goes through the whole thing, then never displays the menu even though the debugger processes that line, and moves on to the next bit of code.

```
if(game.checkForPromotion(startRow, startCol)){
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(GameActivity.this);
    builder.setTitle("Pick a piece")
    .setItems(R.array.pieces_array, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            // The 'which' argument contains the index position
            // of the selected item
        }
    });
    builder.create().show();
    Log.d("GameActivity: ", "Is it crashing before this?");
}

Log.d("GameActivity: ", "Totally done with alert");

// More Code
```

Comment: what's // More Code? it can be important, can you post your entire class?

Comment: can you show us more of that whole block of code?

Comment: Show your adb logs here.

Comment: Can you paste R.array.pieces_array?

Answer (score 0):

I run with your source code, I change value of **[R.array.pieces_array]** to my variable **[final CharSequence[] items = {"This is content of setItems"};]**.
I run program and alert dialog show OK.
Source code show dialog OK:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    final CharSequence[] items = {"This is content of setItems"};
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);
    builder.setTitle("Pick a piece")
            .setItems(items, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    // The 'which' argument contains the index position
                    // of the selected item
                }
            });
    builder.create().show();
    Log.d("GameActivity: ", "Is it crashing before this?");
}
```

I think you need check other source code in file.

Comment: This is not an answer. You are not providing any solution. Put such information in comments only

Answer (score 0):

Try this, it works for me

```
new AlertDialog.Builder(getContext(), android.R.style.Theme_DeviceDefault_Light_Dialog_NoActionBar_MinWidth)
                    .setTitle("Title")
                    .setMessage("My message")
                    .setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

                            // get ok button click

                        }
                    })
                    .setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

                            // get cancel button click
                            dialog.dismiss();
                        }
                    })
                    .show();
```